# I have two files: mys.nuc and ms.prep and need to use bioseq to extract the ORF sequences and save as “mys.nuc2”

Tags: fasta, ngs

Below are the two files I am working with:

```
$ cat mys.pep
>00001 16 324  len=309
LDRFYTKKVIMYKQQYFISGKVQGVGFRFFTEQIANNMKLKGFVKNLNDGRVEIVAFFNT
KEQMKKFEKLLNGNKYSNIKNIEKIVLDENYPFQFNDFKIYY*
>00002 751 308  len=398
YKLYNILLIKYFLIFPKYIDNA*I*KNKNYFKTFLLDRFYTKKVIMYKQQYFISGKVQGV
GFRFFTEQIANNMKLKGFVKNLNDGRVEIVAFFNTKEQMKKFEKLLNGNKYSNIKNIEKI

$cat mys.nuc
>00001  16 324  len=309
TTGGATAGATTTTATACAAAGAAGGTAATAATGTATAAACAACAATATTTTATTTCTGGC
AAGGTGCAAGGTGTTGGTTTTAGATTTTTCACAGAGCAAATAGCAAATAATATGAAACTA
AAAGGATTTGTAAAAAATCTCAACGATGGAAGGGTAGAAATTGTAGCTTTCTTTAATACT
AAAGAACAAATGAAAAAATTTGAAAAATTATTAAATGGGAATAAGTATTCAAACATTAAA
AACATTGAAAAAATAGTTTTAGATGAAAATTATCCTTTTCAATTTAATGATTTTAAAATT
TATTATTAG
>00002  751 308  len=398
TACAAATTATATAATATCTTATTAATAAAATATTTCCTAATATTTCCCAAATATATTGAT
AATGCCTGAATTTAAAAAAACAAAAACTATTTTAAAACTTTTCTATTGGATAGATTTTAT
ACAAAGAAGGTAATAATGTATAAACAACAATATTTTATTTCTGGCAAGGTGCAAGGTGTT
GGTTTTAGATTTTTCACAGAGCAAATAGCAAATAATATGAAACTAAAAGGATTTGTAAAA
AATCTCAACGATGGAAGGGTAGAAATTGTAGCTTTCTTTAATACTAAAGAACAAATGAAA
AAATTTGAAAAATTATTAAATGGGAATAAGTATTCAAACATTAAAAACATTGAAAAAATA
GTTTTAGATGAAAATTATCCTTTTCAATTTAATGATTT
```

What I have done so far is try to run:

```
$ bioseq -B mys.nuc
```

and get:

```
00001
00002
```

Ultimately I am mean to extract the ORF sequence and save as `mys.nuc2` and then translate `mys.nuc2` with `bioseq -t1` where that file should NOT contain any internal stop codons.

I do not understand why I get:

```
00001
00002
```

Or what I am meant to do with it, if that indeed is the correct output.

Comment: Can you run, `which bioseq` and `whereis bioseq`?  Also could you add the `head bioseq` to be sure? How confident are you with writing your own script to find ORF, or download and install (if you can) new tools to do it for you?